# awaiting tasks resulted from ContinueWith chaining

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, continuewith

I am chaining tasks with ContinueWith and await them all.  When I introduce a delay inside the loop (commented - which meant there is *enough time* for tasks to complete), I could see that all tasks are completed. When I remove the delay, I could see only the first message is handled. Remaining messages are not handled. I assume code exits method before completing all the tasks. Not sure if I am awaiting wrongly.

How do I make sure that all my tasks are completed without introducing delay inside the loop?

```
using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialConcurrentJobsCount, maxConcurrentJobsCount))
{
     for(int counter = 0; counter < msgs.Length; counter++)
        {
            tasks[counter] = throttler.WaitAsync()
                                    .ContinueWith(r => new VirtualMachineActor().HandleAsync(msgs[counter]))
                                    .ContinueWith(o => throttler.Release());

                // When below line is present, all tasks are completed properly. 
                // When removed only first msg is executed.
                await Task.Delay(1000);  
       } 
       await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: You should not use `ConinueWith`. Use `await` instead.

Comment: @StephenCleary, I have updated the question based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others, "ContinueWith" chain doesn't necessarily mean sequential order of task execution. It is a wrapper hence needed "UnWrap".